# How do I convert an edge list to a DCEL data structure?

Tags: c++, algorithm, computational-geometry, triangulation

I have a triangulation represented in the form of an *edge list*, but I need to get it in the form of a DCEL (doubly connected edge list).

Is there any fast algorithm to convert an edge list to a DCEL?

Comment: Could you edit your question to give details about the edge list form you're getting and the DCEL form you need? There are many possibilities, and they will affect the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is always the obvious way. Add a back link to every list item: Walk once through your list using two iterators one at one position behind the other one and add the back link.

---

Even simpler would be to just use the [`std::list` class](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/). It is a DCEL, so you may just convert your current list to an `std::list`.